# How to compare two and find first and last value of first array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two array and I have to find second array key with first array value compare with each other.

My first array is

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [C10359] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 89785
                    [1] => 89786
                    [2] => 89857
                )
            [C10899] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 52924
                    [1] => 52945
                    [2] => 52975
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [C10370] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 89785
                    [1] => 89786
                    [2] => 89857
                )
            [C10988] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 52924
                    [1] => 52945
                    [2] => 52975
                )
        )       
)
```

My second array is

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [C10359] => 89860.5
            [C10899] => 53079
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [C10988] => 89860.5
            [C10111] => 53079
        )
)
```

I have to find second array key **C10359** into first array. If match then I want this array first and last value

```
   [C10359] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 89785
                    [1] => 89786
                    [2] => 89857
                )
```

My tried code

```
 $vals = array();
    foreach ($first_array as $k => $v) {
        foreach($v as $key=>$val) {
            if (in_array($val, $second_array)) {
                $value = abs((($val - $second_array)/$second_array)*100);
                    if($value < 25){
                        return $vals ;
                    }
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: And what have you tried in order to get the desired functionality?

Comment: You want to compare and know difference or match ?

Comment: is the structure of the arrays always the same ? each array contains two array and they have all unique keys?

Comment: @Federico Yes structure of the arrays are always same. Each array contains more than two. And arrays are dynamic

Comment: I have updated the solution ... see if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and second arrays are multi dimensional : (array inside array).

You can try flatten them to make the search easier

```
$first_array_flat = array();
foreach($first_array as $a){
    $first_array_flat += $a;
}

$second_array_flat = array();
foreach($second_array as $a){
    $second_array_flat += $a;
}


foreach($second_array_flat as $k=>$v){
    if(isset($first_array_flat[$k])){
        $a = $first_array_flat[$k];
        $first_v = reset($a);
        $last_v = end($a);

        #..... do your stuff here ...
    }
}
```

Comment: i have multiple C id so i can't define $k

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to compare this with [array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php). Then you can use [reset()](https://www.php.net/reset) and [end()](https://www.php.net/end) for finding first and last value of array here is the example:

```
<?php
$arr = array(1,5,6,8,9);
$first_array = reset($arr);
$last_array = end($arr);
?>
```

Output:

```
1
9
```